# How to plot two specific columns from a csv file in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, floating-point

I am new to python and may be missing some details when attempting to plot. I am trying to call upon a specific csv file and plot two columns form the file. I have successfully called upon those columns and converted irrelevant values to NaN. I am now attempting to plot the columns in a line graph to obtain a time series. I am getting an error that I need to convert to float which I tried but it gave me the error that the float must be a string or a number. I had to convert the values in the csv file from a string to a list to make irrelevant values nan, so now i have to switch them back to plot? Once the column is being read correctly by python, is the way in which I have plotted it correct?

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import pandas


def getColumn(filename, column):
    results = csv.reader(open(filename), dialect='excel')
    return [result[column] for result in results]

time = getColumn("C:\Users\dfmcg\Documents\Thesisfiles\ALL_GPMP_O3_Met\ASIS-MA.csv",1)

time = time[1:]
ozone = getColumn("C:\Users\dfmcg\Documents\Thesis files\ALL_GPMP_O3_Met\ASIS-MA.csv",2)
ozone = list(map(int,ozone[1:]))

for i in range (0,len(ozone)):
    if ozone[i] == -999:
        ozone[i] = np.nan
float(ozone)

x = ozone
y = time

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show
```

ABBR    DATE             O3 SWS VWS SWD VWD SDWD    TMP RH  RNF SOL
CASA-GD 07/01/2005 00   -999                        -999    -999
CASA-GD 07/01/2005 01   -999                        -999    -999
CASA-GD 07/01/2005 02   -999                        -999    -999
CASA-GD 07/01/2005 03   -999                        -999    -999
CASA-GD 07/01/2005 04   -999                        -999    -999
CASA-GD 07/01/2005 05   -999                        -999    -999
CASA-GD 07/01/2005 06   -999                        -999    -999
CASA-GD 07/01/2005 07   -999                        -999    -999
CASA-GD 07/01/2005 08   -999                        -999    -999
CASA-GD 07/01/2005 09   -999                        -999    -999
CASA-GD 07/01/2005 10   -999                        -999    -999
CASA-GD 07/01/2005 11   -999                        -999    -999

Comment: Can you post a few lines of your csv along with the full error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check the type of the elements of your list with

```
print type(ozone[0])
```

maybe then you can see where the error originates from

tldr comments: The ozone values were integer types, the included NaN values were floats. Seemingly you cannot plot two different types. This can be solved by setting everything to float

```
 [float(x) for x in ozone]
```

Comment: I just get the error:  
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number

Comment: when I comment out the float(ozone) and do as you suggested I gethe the type is Float

Comment: iterate through it to see if all  of your elements are floats  by for i in range (ozone.shape[0]):

Comment: I get the error: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'

Comment: sorry I thought that was a numpy array , in trhis case the code is for x in ozone: print type(x)

Comment: okay, it would appear that my NaN's are float and my numbers are int. How can this be fixed?

Comment: The benefit of python is that "type casts" are very easy  [float(i) for i in ozone]

Comment: Awesome! so to plot all values must be float type?

Comment: Not necessarily I guess they all have to have the same type. I post a tldr under my answer, would you accept it than?

Comment: It has been accepted, Could you answer one more question? my code is now jut infinitely running so I may have added an infinte loop or something. The file is large but not outrageous so it should run through and plot quickly but it is not. Here is my new code:

Comment: for i in range (0,len(ozone)):
    if ozone[i] == -999:
        ozone[i] = np.nan
for x in ozone:
    [float(i) for i in ozone]
    #print type(x) 
x = ozone
y = time
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show

Comment: I cannot see your code do you want to open a new question? ah there it is

Comment: It's just the part I changed

Comment: just set an else to your 999 if clause that  says  else: ozone[i] = float(ozone[i]) , you do not need the for loop to print the types any more and you do not need   [for x in ozone ...] anymore

Comment: okay, the code has made it down to the plot and I get this error: ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 06/01/2005 00--->which is from my time column
 It also doesn't like something about the plt.plot function. is plt.plot not the correct syntax?

Comment: is your result a matrix so something like [[CASA-GD, 07/01/2005, 01, -999, -999, -999,], [CASA-GD, 07/01/2005, 01, -999, -999 ,-999]] ?

Comment: If so you could also try logical indexing for  example: logIDX =  ozone[:,3] == -999    ozone[logIDX] = np.nan

Comment: it is from a csv file so it is just one column, it is reading it as a string. Is there a specific way to treat dates?

Comment: You can treat dates as a signal number using

from datetime import date

print date.toordinal(date(1970,1,1))

719163

Comment: I would like to axis to read the date as is. is there a way to keep the date but still plot the data? Does the time need to be a float or is a string okay?

Comment: the date also changes, would I iterate through with a for loop?